# Prevent elastic scroll on Safari iPad

Tags: css, ipad, safari

I have implemented the following code to prevent the screen from allowing the user to see the elastic overflow of the site when using an ipad.

```
.main-layout::ng-deep {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  //overflow: hidden;
}
```

The code seems to be working fine, but now the footer at the bottom of the page is getting cut off, this only seems to be an issue on IOS safari. I want the footer to remain at the bottom of the page without it getting cut off. I have seen solutions to this using JavaScript but Ideally I only want to use CSS.

So I have the fix in place where I prevent the elastic scroll. But the footer is being cut off and the user can not scroll down to see it.

Here is the CSS for the footer

```
.footer {
    @media (max-width: $screen-sm-max) {
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    @media (max-width: $screen-sm-min) {
      font-size: 10px;
    }
    @extend .center;
    height: $header-height;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: $gray-ltr;
    font-size: 14px;
    overflow: auto;
    border-top: 2px solid $gray-lt;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've had a similar problem trying to make a web application for iOS on iPhone. Not sure its going to help you on an iPad but worth a try.

I couldn't find any one stop CSS or JS to fix this. Its frustrating when you don't want to pull any extra white down from the top of safari iOS browswer.

The work aground I used that might help you is to do this with CSS is...

```
HTML,
BODY {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  @include position(fixed, 0 0 0 0);
}

.webapp-container {
  @include position(absolute, 0 0 0 0);
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Position is using [bourbon](https://www.bourbon.io/), you can just write position normally if you're not using bourbon.

Add an extra div with HTML...

```
<body>
  <div class="webapp-container">
    New body content with no elastic scrolling
  </div>
</body>
```

Your footer doesn't seem to have any any fixed positioning so you shouldn't have any issues with your original code inside this method.

Comment: This works perfectly! And prevents elastic scroll on Samsungs galaxy update.
For those using vanilla css:
```position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;```